# Google chart API via CURL or PHP into Google Sheets?

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I am looking to import a google charts graph made via the API in php / curl into a google sheets document via the google sheets v4 API. There are docs for importing ["charts" into google sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/response#AddChartResponse). You can also [import images](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateEmbeddedObjectPositionRequest) which I know the charts API allows. So I am wondering if there is anyway in PHP to create a chart in the charts API and then import that chart into the sheets API that is either a fully fledged interactive chart, or an image. Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure how to created charts to google sheets but you can use [Google Apps Script Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/?csw=1). Here is a [blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/visualize-your-data-charts-in-google.html) discussing how to automate chart creation in Google Apps and make the sometimes-tedious tasks of chart creation and updating it. There is also a SO [ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17436833/5995040) how to make an image of the chart using Apps Script and embedding it to Google Sheet.

Comment: There is also a [blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/06/programmatically-managing-charts-in.html) about "Programmatically Managing Charts" in Spreadsheets. Using App Script you can create a function that will check if any of the ranges need to be expanded (i.e. if there are more rows with data to display). It then updates the title, builds the new EmbeddedChart object and saves it to the sheet. It could also add a menu interface or a trigger to execute this periodically or when the spreadsheet is edited.