# Is it possible to convert a Chart to and EmbeddedChart?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, embedded-resource

I'm attempting to Create a few charts out of a Sheet of data, but the charts are grabbing sort of specific data so I have found it advantageous to use the DataTableBuilder class. I am able to specify labels for the data more easily than I can from the original sheet. However, I cannot embed a Chart Class into a Sheet. Is it possible to either convert a Chart to an EmbeddedChart or use a DataTable to create an EmbeddedChart?I'm attempting to Create a few charts out of a Sheet of data, but the charts are grabbing sort of specific data so I have found it advantageous to use the DataTableBuilder class. I am able to specify labels for the data more easily than I can from the original sheet. However, I cannot embed a Chart Class into a Sheet. Is it possible to either convert a Chart to an EmbeddedChart or use a DataTable to create an EmbeddedChart?

This is the data below, and I need only the last column (5/11) and I don't need the total row. So its not a concise range, else I would just use the Embedded chart builder.

```
    May          5/1    5/2 5/3 5/11    
    Critical       0    0   0   0   
    High           0    0   0   0   
    Call Immediate  4   11  4   3   
    Daytime Call    3   3   6   1   
    Totals         7    14  10  4
```

Below is the how I've built the Chart in which dailyTotals is a range of [0, 0, 3, 1]. This works fine, but I can't label anything.

```
      var dailyChart = LOB.newChart()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
        .setOption('title', LOB.getName())
        .addRange(dailyTotals)
        .build();
      LOB.insertChart(dailyChart);
```

Below is building the DataTable, this time daily totals is just an array. But this gives me labels.

```
    dailyTable = Charts.newDataTable()
     .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Priority")
     .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Incidents")
     .addRow('P1', dailyTotals[0])
     .addRow('P2', dailyTotals[1])
     .addRow('P3', dailyTotals[2])
     .addRow('P4', dailyTotals[3])
    .build();
```

How can I either use a DataTable to create an EmbeddedChart? or how can I turn a Chart into and Embedded chart?

Comment: Best I have so far is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287688/how-to-embed-google-visualization-chart-into-spreadsheet) which utilized UIApp to render it an image, but that's deprecated and pretty useless at this juncture.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to re-create the below range somewhere else in the sheet and add that as range instead.

```
A  B
P1 0   
P2 0   
P3 3   
P4 1
```

The range [P1, P2, P3, P4] can also be somewhere else. Then you can add both ranges:

```
.addRange([P1 to P4 range])
.addRange(dailyTotals)
.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain','true')
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out a solution that worked for me before I got a response from anyone. It involves using a legend to determine which bar is which, rather than labels along the x-axis, but it totally covers my requirements and might help out some one else out.

```
  var dailySeries =  {
   0:{color: 'blue', labelInLegend: 'P1'},
   1:{color: 'red', labelInLegend: 'P2'},
   2:{color: 'yellow', labelInLegend: 'P3'},
   3:{color: 'green', labelInLegend: 'P4'}
  }  
  var dailyChart = LOB.newChart()
   .setPosition(8, 27, 0, 0)
   .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
   .asColumnChart()
   .setOption('title', LOB.getName())
   .addRange(dailyTotals.getCell(1, 1))
   .addRange(dailyTotals.getCell(2, 1))
   .addRange(dailyTotals.getCell(3, 1))
   .addRange(dailyTotals.getCell(4, 1))
   .setOption('series', dailySeries)
   .build();
 LOB.insertChart(dailyChart);
```

Comment: I thought so too. Its probably not conventional or the way it was intended to be used, but it worked for what I needed, so I'm not mad about it.